# How to find files with a certain subpath?

Tags: find, grep, regular-expression, console, file-search

I need to find all xml-files that are placed in folders named `config`. Also `config` must be somewhere under a folder named `trunk`. For example, I am interested in all files like below:

```
~/projects/e7/trunk/a/b/c/config/foo.xml
~/projects/d/trunk/config/bar.xml
~/projects/trunk/config/other.xml
~/projects/e/e/e/trunk/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/e/config/eeeee.xml
```

I tried the `find` command:

```
find ~/projects -regex "*/trunk/*/config/*.xml"
```

, but the output was empty. What is the correct way to find the required files?

Comment: You do need `-regex` if you want to make sure that only files from a directory `config` are returned unless you can guarantee that no directory `config` has subdirectories (which have a `*.xml` in their tree).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not a regex. For globs one should use the `-path` predicate instead.

Comment: Thank you. It works `find ~/projects -path "*/trunk*/config/*.xml"`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what you want to do with the files after you find them, but for interactive use in `zsh` I would use something like this:

```
ls **/trunk/**/config/*.xml
```

Comment: Actually, I'd like to look in some files from recieved list. After your answer, I became interested in `zsh` and installed it. But unfortunately you command-line didn't work. I tried to modify your command (for example `ls ~/projects '**/trunk/**/config/*.xml' --recursive`) but without success.

Comment: Ah I forgot, `zsh` doesn't do much with the default settings, you need to put `setopt EXTENDED_GLOB` in `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) or [my zshrc](https://github.com/phunehehe/terminal-dotfiles/blob/master/_zshrc).